# How to make sidenav mobile link in react js about this situation?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make the sidenav mobile to show when clicking.

I tried to use jquery, but don't know how to configure in webpack.

```
const SignedOutLinks = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavLink to="#" className="sidenav-trigger nav-wrapper" data-target="mobile-links">
                <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
            </NavLink>
            <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li className="waves-effect waves-light">
                    <NavLink to="/signup">Signup</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="waves-effect waves-light">
                    <NavLink to="/signin">Login</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul className="sidenav" id="mobile-links">
                <li className="waves-effect waves-light">
                    <NavLink to="/signup">Signup</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="waves-effect waves-light">
                    <NavLink to="/signin">Login</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Why would you use jquery when you are using react? This destroys the point of a whole another library.

Comment: I thought it would be more effective. Any idea using javascript instead of jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write it, this is some code i make:

or [this link](https://codepen.io/alibalouchi/pen/dxgOMe)

react:

```
class Drawer extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     open: false,
    }
  }

  handleDrawer(){
    let currentState = this.state.open
    this.setState({open: !currentState})
  }

  componentDidMount(){
        if (this.state.open = true){
            document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
                if (event.keyCode === 27){
                    this.setState({open: false})
                }    
             })
        }
    }

  handleClickOut(){
    if(this.state.open === true){
      this.setState({open: false})
    }
  }

   render(){
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div>
        <div 
          onClick={this.handleClickOut.bind(this)} 
          className={this.state.open ? "deactive" : "container"}>
        <button onClick={this.handleDrawer.bind(this)}>Click on me to see the 
drawer</button>
        </div>
        <div className={this.state.open ? "active" : "drawer"}>Hellllo i'm a 
drawer</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Drawer
```

css:

```
.drawer {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: show;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #C10E00;
  transition: display 0.4s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.deactive {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF5346;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #910B00;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px grey;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

or if you want to get it full coded you can use [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/) framework